# I got an error when I try to delete an image in docker

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-registry, docker-image

System version: ubuntu 14.04
Docker version: 1.0.1, build 990021a

I am new to docker, I try the command

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 registry
```

But it takes a long time. And I feel it is too long. So I pressed  `ctrl + c`  to stop this operation. Then, I tried

```
docker pull registry
```

But it occured some errors.  I worried about it so i restart the system. Then I input `docker images`. There are many images named none, and when I try to delete it, it will return an error. See the picture.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq4W9.png)

Comment: The error is:     Error response from daemon: Error while getting parent image: Id can't be empty

Comment: It seems something wrong with my docker. Because I even can't delete the image  hello-world. And it is the same problem:Error response from daemon: Error while getting parent image: Id can't be empty
2015/10/21 19:52:12 Error: failed to remove one or more images

Comment: Sorry, I found that the hello-world images was deleted, but it shows the same error code. However, when i tried `docker images`, it is just gone.

Answer (score 0):

You might have encountered this bug: https://github.com/Strider-CD/strider-dockerfile/issues/7

One of the comments says that

> You could always kill the docker daemon...

If stopping the daemon (`service docker stop`) you can kill it either with `pkill docker` or by looking up the PID from `ps aux | grep docker` and then killing the process with `kill -9 <PID>`.

Does this help you?

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I don't think the bug is  same. And I still not sure what should I do to kill the docker daemon.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.